# Как удалить файл из папки Assets?

Tags: android, android-assets

В папке `assets/` находится файл, который после процедур с ним подлежит удалению. В документации по `AssetsManager` ничего такого не нашёл. Есть ли способ совершить такую операцию?

Comment: Невозможно редактировать assets в рантайме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет способа.
Все ресурсы приложения `readonly`, включая `assets`, ни удалить, ни изменить.